# Dendrites (ionic contamination) on home-brew PCBs

Tags: pcb

I've been making PCBs myself for 5 years already.

- I use UV curing
- develop in NaON (SodiumHydroxide)
- etch in Na2S2O8 (Sodium Persulfate)
- clean finished PCB with acetone

Recently, I've noticed variety of weird glitches with newly made PCBs - hundred kilo-ohm resistance across separate tracks, power leaks, self-resetting MCUs and self-flashing LEDs or self-turning FETs.

When inspecting PCBs under volates (up to 12V) i've noticed weird spots growing in front of my eyes. Absolutely clean PCB gets dirty in approx. 60 seconds.

Further inspection led to a single conclusion - DENDRITES (or ionic contamination).

I've thrown away all my chemicals and ordered a new set of blank PCB material.
I've event replaced standard water with the distilled-one as well as bought new welding Flux (Weller).

I do still get the same effect.

What else should I try?

ps: PCB in the photos below was crystal clean 60 seconds before powering it up with a 12V rail.

[image: Dendrites-2]

[image: Dendrites-1]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisker_(metallurgy) ?

Comment: Nope, these are not Whiskers. It can be obviously seen from the photos in this article 
http://nepp.nasa.gov/Whisker/background/index.htm

Comment: It's hard (for me) to tell  from the images in post but if they're planar, they're indeed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrite_(metal)

Comment: I have no idea how to fix your problem, but for background on dendrites http://www.te.com/documentation/whitepapers/pdf/p313-89.pdf seems a good read.

Comment: Is this happening with the blank copper already or only after you put the solder onto everything?

Comment: So far I did only a quick test on a blank PCB after I have washed it with water. Applied 12V (high current capable battery) on most of tracks - nothing. After washing with acetone and soldering - dendrites grow simultaneously with the same 12V battery connected.

I do have a feeling that load is needed for a proper test, and I did a test w/o load.

Comment: After a brief look at that TE doc, you're probably seeing "humid" electromigration. Try baking the PCBs before using/solering them to eliminate as much moisture as possible.

Comment: My comment wasn't 100% clear. Is the tinning of the tracks actually needed for increased current carrying capability or could you leave it out and test it with a load on blank copper - maybe it's happening just on parts with solder on.

Comment: @Arsenal: I'm guessing he's also using solder as poor man's solder mask and/or conformal coating, i.e. to prevent long-time corrosion of copper.

Comment: @Arsenal, yes, I've tinned the tracks to increase the current flow (I've eliminated the ground plane since dendrites caused each track surrounded by ground to virtually disappear).  But I normally do it to prevent corrosion as well. 
However, I have made similar PCB w/o tinning the tracks - still the same problem. Dendrites on copper parts too...

Comment: @FlegmatoidZoid okay. I've looked through the TE document as well and it specifically mentions copper sulphide, so maybe your etchant is the cause (it contains sulphur). I just checked what kind of etchant we are using in our company and it is iron (III) chloride - ugly stuff, but it contains no sulphur. But still no explanation why it suddenly happened.

Comment: You swapped almost all of your materials - but did you also try with a different solder?

Comment: Nope, solder is the same.
In fact, I've made another PCB few hours ago. I didn't cover the tracks with solder this time. Still, Dendrites do grow from those too. I have then tried to wash the final board with distilled water (whereas I normally finish with acetone), and it seems further dendrite grow has stopped. Either it has saturated, or it really has to do something with an Acetone.

Comment: That looks to me like a very thin film left by incomplete etching - it has a substantial area, not just thin whiskers. I had something similar sometimes when I made my own boards. Just something to consider?

Comment: @Brian, that I did not consider. Might definitely be the root cause. Will run an experiment to confirm/disprove this.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question as I was able to identify the root cause.

**It is due to Flux.** I am using Weller F-SW12 ([datasheet](http://lemona.lt/LIUSE/TI/En/Pdf/Weller_flux_SDS.pdf))
I haven't experienced problems in the past because my PCBs were mostly for 3.3V/miliAmpere range (however, quartz filtering capacitors were often going crazy, now I know why).
The dendrites have appeared due to multiple factors:

- High Voltages (relatively) - up to 16V
- High Currents (relatively) - 30+ Amperes
- Non-perfect Acetone bathing (for excess Flux cleaning)
- Not washing final PCBs with distilled water

**Normally, after acetone bathing I was drying PCBs. That process was leaving a thin layer of highly diluted Flux, thus spreading that Flux across the entire board.**

I fact, I was able to recover "contaminated" PCBs by re-washing those with acetone and then intensively washing it all under the running water, finally rinsing everything in the distilled water.

To prevent future PCBs from dendrite formation I have replaced the Weller flux with simple rosin/alcohol fluid and have not observed dendrite growth ever since. Furthermore, this mixture doesn't require to be carefully treated/washed as is not conductive to electricity (It seems).

[image: Weller F-SW12]

Comment: Well, that "flux" in your picture is actually never a good idea for electronic soldering. It's quite a strong beast for plumbing, gutters and other "heavy metal"; the label says: "iron, steel, copper, brass and tinned sheet metal" And it says: "Remove any remaining flux [after soldering]!"

Comment: +1 at @zebonaut's comment. It also recommends safety glasses and gloves and extractor hood. _S26_ means __very toxic when in contact to skin or inhaled__. This is  really good stuff to make iron or heavily oxidated stuff solderable, but residues of the zinc-chloride may corrode tiny structures on a PCB.

Comment: absolutely, lesson learned. In fact, datasheet is somehow missing those guidelines which are on the bottle (I don't read German). Nor it seems to have characteristics on conductivity etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your findings. Often enough here someone will post a fairly mysterious problem, gets a bunch of suggestions, but we never hear back on what the problem actually was... Interesting enough this cause of dendrite growth (acid medium left on the board) didn't get much coverage in the sources I've looked at. They all emphasized humidity. But higher currents/voltages were definitely known to be a factor.

Answer (score 1):

This comes about due to the reduction of lead in solder and tin alloys.
NASA has done research into this and one solution is to coat the board with a 'conformal' coating: " NASA GSFC experiments have shown that use of Arathane 5750 (formerly Uralane 5750) conformal when applied uniformly to a nominal 2 to 3 mils thickness can provide significant benefit by containing whisker growth outward through the coating. "

More can be found on NASA's page about Tin Whiskers (dendrites) here:
http://nepp.nasa.gov/Whisker/background/index.htm

Comment: The article you mention is about whiskers, not dendrites... And as NASA says in its own article, they are not the same. The OP looks confident his problem is not about whiskers but dendrites, so your answer might be out topic.

Comment: ... Or maybe not, but then I think you should really explain why you think the issue is actually whiskers... : )

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link might help

http://www.edifgroup.com/case-studies/contamination-and-moisture-effects-on-printed-circuit-board-reliability

Certainly looks like some form of contamination though

Comment: When this link dies, your answer won't have any information in it. Can you add the important details from this link to your post?

Comment: Among the causes listed in that paper are "Ionic contamination [that] can arise from fluxes used during soldering processes". Which was actually the main cause here. The paper also mentions the testing standards in this respect that are performed at factory for boards: "The development of standards of cleanliness and standard test methods date back to the early 1970’s in the US, culminating in the publication of the original American MIL standards. It was from this work that the original pass/fail criteria of 10µg NaCl equivalence per square inch or 1.56µg per cm2 were first proposed."